# Android Studio - same menu for all activities (Navigation Drawer)

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm new to Android Studio (and also pretty new to javascrips), so this might be a stupid question.

I do not want to maintain the same code more than once if possible, which is why I am trying to create a navigation-menu, to be used in all my activities.

So far I have created a "BaseActivity" that contains all the functions for my menu. This one works fine.

Now my problem:

In my other activities I can not get it to show up (not without issues anyway). It seems to me like it overwrites the layout.

My base ("BaseActivity"):

```
public  class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.Open, R.string.Close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    NavigationView NavigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
{
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, content, true);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id==R.id.nav_Home) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
    else
    if(id==R.id.nav_Activity1) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity1.class));

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

}

If I change the app to start through this activity the menu works, but the layout seems to be overwritten (it's empty). 
When I try to run it normally (MainActivity), I get some issues.

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); }}
```

The menu-icon is there, but I can not click on it.

If I remove the code in my MainActivity it works as before (with the layout problem).

I have tried something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, content, true);
}}
```

Not working well. The layout from MainActivity seems to be implemented in the menu. It looks very strange.

Any ideas how to solve my problem?